# Add custom security attribute as optional claim in Azure app

Tags: azure-active-directory

In the Azure AD of the company I work for there is a custom security attribute on users called customerid. When a user authenticates I would like this customerid attribute to be included in the ID token, so the authenticating application can use it.

I have tried to add it into the app manifest like this for example, but with no success:

```
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "customerid",
            "source": "b2c.customerid",
            "essential": false
        }
    ]}
```

I don't find much documentation for the optionalClaims attribute in the Azure app manifest documentation, so that is why I am guessing. Can this be done in some way? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Could you confirm whether you want to include **custom** claim in normal Azure AD app or Azure AD B2C app?

Comment: According to the Azure admin it is a normal Azure AD app.

Answer (score 1):

> You can add **extension properties** as optional claim in Azure application instead of custom security attributes.

I created one extension property named **`customerid`** by running below query in **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)**:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appObjID/extensionProperties
Content-type: application/json

{
    "name": "customerid",
    "dataType": "String",
    "targetObjects": [
        "User"
    ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To update extension property's value for specific user, I ran below **PATCH** request:

```http
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<upn>
Content-type: application/json

{
  "extension_30b4aef20a19xxxxxxxxxx_customerid": "05092023"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can now add this extension property as **optional claim** in your application like below:

[image]

To confirm that, you can check **`App's Manifest`** where optional claim will be added as below:

[image]

Now, I generated tokens using **authorization code** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <app_ID>
client_secret: <secret> 
scope: openid profile User.Read
code: code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the **id token** in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), it has **`extn.customerid`** claim successfully like below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also create claim mapping policy using **PowerShell** to add custom key and value in **id token** claims.

**Reference:**
[Azure AD Angular Customize login response - Stack Overflow by **me**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568713/azure-ad-angular-customize-login-respose/76593788#76593788)

Comment: Thank you so much for giving this answer, but since I want a custom security attribute and not an extension attribute included in my ID token this won't work. The custom security attributes do not appear in the list when clicking "Add optional claim". So I guess there is no way to get them as a claim in the ID token.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to get custom security attribute as claim in ID token. Check this [similar SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922753/azure-active-directory-and-custom-attributes-in-jwt-security?rq=1).